# A simple example of an Ionic UI that is wired up as a Meteor client?

Tags: angular, mongodb, ionic-framework, meteor

I've started this tutorial several times, without time to complete it with success.  [WhatsApp Clone with Meteor and Ionic 2 CLI](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup)

There are a lot of nuggets in the tutorial, above and it seems thoroughly laid out.  However, it's pretty bloated just to see a simple example of an Ionic UI behaving as a Meteor client.  If any of you could point me in the right direction... it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: At which point exactly did you get stuck? If there is a specific code in the tutorial that is not working for, please add it to your question.

Comment: Though there are many tutorials and examples, I couldn't find any explaining how and why those are coupled together. Most are simply telling:"do this, do that."

Comment: I’m didn’t get stuck so much as I got overwhelmed.   After two days of stepping through it and fixing package versions, typescript etc.... I stopped.   It’s not a sustainable combo from what I can tel

Comment: "After two days of stepping through it and fixing package versions, typescript etc." sounds like the tutorial is using deprecated versions? This happened a lot lately with many Meteor tutorials using outdated or abondoned versions and dependencies.

Comment: "sounds like the tutorial is using deprecated versions?"  It does seem to be the case.  That's why I stopped.  My main objective was to understand how to use a front end framework of choice with Meteor's back end and real time client updates.  This has turned out to be way more complicated/time consuming than expected.

Comment: Hey I found in the source repo, that there is a more recent updated version. It seems, that the tutorial has not update to this version, though. You may check this repo out and run the code there: https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp

Comment: Ok.  Thanks!  I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following I'd like to summarize the situation on Meteor and Angular.

### Deprecated Tutorials

First, [meteor.com](http://meteor.com) has an official self-hosted angular tutorial, but the WhatsApp clone tutorial is referring to a third party developer team, which provides the tutorial and did lots of fundamental work on the Meteor-Angular integration.

The (webpack-) [tutorial you referenced](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup) is (as of today, 2019/01/14) targeting ionic 2 (headline says 3?) and Angular 2 and it's last update was on 2017/06/15.

A similar situation is if you use the [pure Meteor-CLI version of the tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/setup).

In both cases you will end up using very outdated Angular versions (current is 7) and also install mostly incompatible Typescript versions.

### Maintained Main Repo

Now before you waste more time on trying to get the deprecated tech running, you may actually check out the main [Angular-Meteor integration repo](https://github.com/urigo/angular-meteor/).

This repo itself is still maintained (last update on Nov. 2018 as of today) and the builds also succeed.

### Quickstart

A quickstart repo can also be cloned and get you started fast:

```
git clone https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor-base myApp
cd myApp
meteor npm install
meteor
```