# AngularJS-Meteor for meteor version 1.5 or above?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, meteor, angular-meteor

I run angular-meteor just fine on meteor 1.4.2.3. Unfortunately, while trying to upgrade meteor I run into troubles loading angular-meteor module for AngularJS:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-meteor' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=angular-meteor

```
at angular_angular.js:93
at angular_angular.js:2059
at ensure (angular_angular.js:1983)
at Object.module (angular_angular.js:2057)
at template.measurements-card.js (app.js:9)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:346)
at Module.require (modules-runtime.js:248)
at require (modules-runtime.js:268)
at app.js:61832
```

The meteor packages are:

```
meteor-base@1.4.0        
mobile-experience@1.0.5      
mongo@1.6.0                  
session@1.1.7                
jquery               
tracker@1.2.0                 
standard-minifier-css@1.5.2   
standard-minifier-js@2.4.0    
es5-shim@4.8.0                
ecmascript@0.12.4             
accounts-password@1.5.1
dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
practicalmeteor:mocha
shell-server
dynamic-import
underscore
shynah:flex-calendar
momentjs:moment
shynah:angular-wizard
buymybm100:ionic-datepicker
shynah:ionic-timepicker
dburles:mongo-collection-instances
nvd3:nvd3
shynah:angularjs-nvd3-directives
mystec:angular-nvd3
thospaeth:angular-slider
meteorhacks:kadira
kadira:debug
nimble:restivus
meteorhacks:picker
vsivsi:file-collection@1.3.5
ionic-team:ionic
angular-templates
```

Any suggestions why the error occurs?

Comment: I recently summarized the current situation with Angular [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195669/3098783). I posted a link to the most recent repo at the end. Maybe it's documentation helps you.

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read especially [answer].