# getting error: Module 'angular-meteor' is not available (after Meteor 1.8.0.1 update)

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I run a v1.8 meteor-angular app (angularjs 1.7.6) and everything works fine.
After updating to v1.8.0.1 (or v1.8.0.2), server runs fine, but client shows error in devtools and the app does not load:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-meteor' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Any idea what's the issue? what can I check? 
Cheers

Attaching my `.meteor/packages` file for reference:

```
meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mongo@1.6.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
session@1.1.8                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery@1.11.10                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library


jparker:crypto-md5
http@1.4.1
accounts-base@1.4.3
outatime:jwt-simple
edgee:slingshot
mdj:meteor-node-uuid
aldeed:collection2@3.0.0
reactive-var@1.0.11
angular-templates
civilframe:angular-jade
pbastowski:angular-babel
shell-server@0.4.0
dynamic-import@0.5.0
allow-deny@1.1.0
abernix:standard-minifier-js
underscore@1.0.10
fourseven:scss
aldeed:schema-deny
seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
```

Comment: I explained the current situation [to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807162/a-simple-example-of-an-ionic-ui-that-is-wired-up-as-a-meteor-client/54195669#54195669) maybe it helps.

Comment: @Jankapunkt there are quite a few resources/pointers in the post you referenced. Anything specific I should pay close attention to?