# Any Angular2 Meteor Material working example?

Tags: meteor, angular-material2, angular2-meteor, angular2-material

Back in the day I successfully created an app with meteor and blaze, and applied material design to it.

Needless to say, I was very excited meteor and angular were getting paired up, so a few weeks ago I finally got around to giving it a try.

But, no matter what I try, I simply cannot get Material UI to work with angular2-meteor.

I cloned and tried https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially just this morning, can't get it to work - no matter how many errors I fix, it still finds new ones. Now it claims it cannot find the scss and html files, which are right there, even the EDA finds it with ctrl+click.....

I cloned and tried https://github.com/0mkara/meteor-ng-material-baby - same thing, endless errors, can't get it to work...

To make the long story short, **is there any tutorial or clonable package which works with meteor angular2 material?**

Comment: The situation with angular is a bit complicated regarding official support. I tried to explain it in [another meteor-angular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807162/a-simple-example-of-an-ionic-ui-that-is-wired-up-as-a-meteor-client/54195669#54195669). I think the same applies to the 2.0-socially app you referred to in your question. You may open an issue that it should be updated to the latest angular/typescript compilers.

Comment: @Jankapunkt: I am fine with a base angular2-meteor app, it is working just fine. My trouble starts when I try to add any kind of a UI framework/library - then everything falls apart :(

Comment: What about the pure NPM packages, for example the official [@angular/material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material)?